# error: cannot find symbol method openConnection()

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

Хочу в Android Studio получить ответ от сайта, но проблема в том, что не может найти метод `openConnection`, ибо часть кода брал с старых API. На что его можно заменить? Пробовал менять на `HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();` , но тогда не может определить `url`.

Код:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


    String query = "https://test.kulpichev.ru/private/newsFeed/articles/zh.1.json";
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URI(query).openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        //connection.getUseCaches(false);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(300);
        connection.setReadTimeout(300);

        connection.connect();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == connection.getResponseCode()) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "utf8"));

            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("ошибка: " + connection.getResponseCode() + ", " + connection.getResponseMessage());
        }


    } catch (Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) ;
        {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Буковку перепутали - не `URI`, а `URL`. У `URI` никогда не было этого метода.

Comment: И сразу смотрим ответ на Ваш следующий вопрос: [Как починить android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/506132/11515)

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URI(query).toURL().openConnection();
```