# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException при использовании потока

Tags: java, android, сеть

Есть обработчик нажатия кнопки. При нажатии должен выполнится сетевой запрос. 
Написал по уроку простой метод для отправки http-запросов. Получил эту ошибку
**android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException** Почитал, что это связано с тем, что запрос выполняется в UI потоке. Ладно. Создал отдельный поток.

```
public void reportSend(View v)
{
         th =   new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.i("TAG","MSG");

                    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    try {

                        connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL ("http://spaces.ru").openConnection();

                        connection.connect();


                        if(connection.HTTP_OK == connection.getResponseCode())
                        {
                            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( connection.getInputStream(), "cp1251"));


                            String line;
                            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
                            {
                                sb.append(line);
                                sb.append("\n");
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception cause) {
                        cause.printStackTrace();
                        //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, cause.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    finally {
                        if(connection != null)
                            connection.disconnect();
                    }


                    Log.i("NET",  sb.toString());
                }
            });

            th.run();
}
```

Ошибка тем не менее сохранилась прежняя. 
Как выйти из положения?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как починить android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506131/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Вчитайтесь в смысл, вопросы далеко не дубликаты.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод [Thread.run()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run()) выполнит код синхронно, в том же потоке, замените на [start()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start())

Comment: Спасибо огромное!