# Вылетает Андроид приложение при создании телнет-сокета

Tags: java, android, сокет, telnet

Тестировал на десктопе - все работает. На устройстве приложение закрывается при нажатии кнопки. Тестировал и без нее - все тоже самое. Проверял по нескольким гайдам - они работают по примерно тем-же принцапам, но даже при попытке копировать с них проблема остается.

```
package com.example.theonr.reboot2.feature;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnOk;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);

        View.OnClickListener oclBtnCancel = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                action();
            }
        };
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(oclBtnCancel);

    }


    public void action(){

        try {
            System.out.println("Start...");

            Socket pingSocket = null;
            PrintWriter out = null;
            BufferedReader in = null;

            try {
                pingSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.1"), 23);
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(pingSocket.getOutputStream())), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pingSocket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return;
            }

            for(int i=0; i<2; i++) in.readLine();


            out.println("admin");
            for(int i=0; i<1; i++)in.readLine();

            out.println("pwd");
            for(int i=0; i<15; i++)in.readLine();

            out.println("reboot");
            for(int i=0; i<2; i++)in.readLine();

            out.close();
            in.close();
            pingSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}

        System.out.println("Finished!");
    }
}
```

Comment: код ошибки в студию

Comment: У меня нет возможности достать код, так как устройство не подключается к пк для дебага (моя личная проблема, которую сейчас не могу исправить), а непосредственно с него - не знаю как это сделать. Именно по-этому я изначально тестировал на десктопе (благо библиотеки, в целом, одни и те же используются)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как починить android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506131/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: подключите к приложению Fabric. Он сохраняет данные о падении в системе. Можно будет посмотреть эксепшен. Возможно, вы тогда уже и сами сможете исправить ошибку) Но если что - открывайте новый вопрос с кодом ошибки

Comment: Спасибо, займусь этим. Это уже дельный совет)

Comment: Работу с сетью нельзя выполнять в главном потоке.

Comment: Спасибо, еще один совет в копилку, но проблема, видимо, оказалась не только в этом. Сейчас буду смотреть код ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, дело было действительно в потоках (спасибо комментатору). При работе с сетью нельзя было работать в том же потоке, что и основная программа.

Comment: Расширьте ответ, как именно была решена проблема.