# Использую Exposed for Kotlin возникает ошибка. Не могу понять из-за чего это. Соединение или транзакция?

Tags: android, sql, база-данных, sql-server, kotlin

```
        val db = Database.connect(
                    "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:**.**.***.**;databaseName=*********",
                    "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
                    user = "********",
                    password = "********"
                )

        transaction(db){
                    SchemaUtils.create(Events)

                    val event = Events.insert {
                        it[title] = "St. Petersburg"
                        it[location] = 0.2
                        it[description] = "fgdsfd"
                        it[usersCount] = 1
                    }
                }
    object Events : IntIdTable() {
        val title = varchar("title", 20)
        val location = double("location")
        val description = varchar("description", length = 200)
        val usersCount = integer("usersCount")
    }

    class Event(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
        companion object : IntEntityClass<Event>(table = Events)

        var title by Events.title
        var location     by Events.location
        var description by Events.description
        var usersCount by Events.usersCount
    }
```

ОШИБКА:

```
    2019-04-28 15:08:30.812 9601-9601/com.example.fm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.fm, PID: 9601
        java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at com.example.fm.activities.MapActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MapActivity.kt:88)
            at com.example.fm.activities.MapActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MapActivity.kt:36)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.inTopLevelTransaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:104)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:75)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:58)
            at com.example.fm.activities.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.kt:87)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method.callMethod(CallerImpl.kt:97)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Instance.call(CallerImpl.kt:113)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.call(KCallableImpl.kt:106)
            at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KProperty1Impl.get(KProperty1Impl.kt:35)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table.clone(Table.kt:212)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table.cloneWithAutoInc(Table.kt:361)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table.autoIncrement(Table.kt:365)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table.autoIncrement$default(Table.kt:365)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.IntIdTable.<init>(IntEntity.kt:6)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.IntIdTable.<init>(IntEntity.kt:5)
            at com.example.fm.tables.Events.<init>(Events.kt:8)
            at com.example.fm.tables.Events.<clinit>(Events.kt:8)
            at com.example.fm.activities.MapActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MapActivity.kt:88) 
            at com.example.fm.activities.MapActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MapActivity.kt:36) 
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.inTopLevelTransaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:104) 
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:75) 
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:58) 
            at com.example.fm.activities.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.kt:87) 
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383) 
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921) 
         Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The port number 31.31.196.61 is not valid.
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1564)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1077)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:618)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion$connect$7.invoke(Database.kt:114)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion$connect$7.invoke(Database.kt:72)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion$doConnect$3.invoke(Database.kt:93)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion$doConnect$3.invoke(Database.kt:72)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManager$ThreadLocalTransaction$connectionLazy$1.invoke(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:26)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManager$ThreadLocalTransaction$connectionLazy$1.invoke(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:23)
            at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:81)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManager$ThreadLocalTransaction.getConnection(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:32)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Transaction.getConnection(Unknown Source:2)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database.getMetadata$exposed(Database.kt:18)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$url$2.invoke(Database.kt:27)
    2019-04-28 15:08:30.813 9601-9601/com.example.fm E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$url$2.invoke(Database.kt:16)
            at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database.getUrl(Unknown Source:7)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$dialect$2.invoke(Database.kt:30)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$dialect$2.invoke(Database.kt:16)
            at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database.getDialect(Unknown Source:7)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.vendors.DefaultKt.getCurrentDialect(Default.kt:363)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.vendors.DefaultKt.getCurrentDialectIfAvailable(Default.kt:367)
            at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Column.getOnDelete$exposed(Column.kt:17)
                ... 31 more
```

ЕСЛИ задавать без localhost ОШИБКА:

```
2019-05-05 17:47:05.262 12402-12402/com.example.fm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fm, PID: 12402
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.example.fm.activities.MapActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MapActivity.kt:89)
        at com.example.fm.activities.MapActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MapActivity.kt:36)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.inTopLevelTransaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:104)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:75)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:58)
        at com.example.fm.activities.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.kt:87)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method.callMethod(CallerImpl.kt:97)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Instance.call(CallerImpl.kt:113)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.call(KCallableImpl.kt:106)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KProperty1Impl.get(KProperty1Impl.kt:35)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table.clone(Table.kt:212)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table.cloneWithAutoInc(Table.kt:361)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table.autoIncrement(Table.kt:365)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table.autoIncrement$default(Table.kt:365)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.IntIdTable.<init>(IntEntity.kt:6)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.IntIdTable.<init>(IntEntity.kt:5)
        at com.example.fm.tables.Events.<init>(Events.kt:8)
        at com.example.fm.tables.Events.<clinit>(Events.kt:8)
        at com.example.fm.activities.MapActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MapActivity.kt:89) 
        at com.example.fm.activities.MapActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MapActivity.kt:36) 
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.inTopLevelTransaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:104) 
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:75) 
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:58) 
        at com.example.fm.activities.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.kt:87) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921) 
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1460)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:851)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Util.lookupHostName(Util.java:661)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2236)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1921)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1762)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1077)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:618)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion$connect$7.invoke(Database.kt:114)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion$connect$7.invoke(Database.kt:72)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion$doConnect$3.invoke(Database.kt:93)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion$doConnect$3.invoke(Database.kt:72)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManager$ThreadLocalTransaction$connectionLazy$1.invoke(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:26)
2019-05-05 17:47:05.263 12402-12402/com.example.fm E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManager$ThreadLocalTransaction$connectionLazy$1.invoke(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:23)
        at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:81)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManager$ThreadLocalTransaction.getConnection(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:32)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Transaction.getConnection(Unknown Source:2)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database.getMetadata$exposed(Database.kt:18)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$url$2.invoke(Database.kt:27)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$url$2.invoke(Database.kt:16)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database.getUrl(Unknown Source:7)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$dialect$2.invoke(Database.kt:30)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$dialect$2.invoke(Database.kt:16)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database.getDialect(Unknown Source:7)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.vendors.DefaultKt.getCurrentDialect(Default.kt:363)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.vendors.DefaultKt.getCurrentDialectIfAvailable(Default.kt:367)
        at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Column.getOnDelete$exposed(Column.kt:17)
            ... 31 more
```

Comment: Проблема здесь: `localhost:**.**.***.**` - вместо `<host>:<port>` Вы указали два хоста (локальной машины и удалённый). Пробуйте так: `"jdbc:sqlserver://**.**.***.**;databaseName=*********"`. Если используется дефолтный порт - его можно не указывать.

Comment: Пробовал и без localhost, не помогает

Comment: Не помогает, или выдаёт другую ошибку? Это как бы не одно и тоже...

Comment: Та же ошибка, что и выше

Comment: Если та же - значит вы не убрали двоеточие перед ip-адресом (хотя тогда,  по идее, драйвер должен ругаться на отсутствие хоста) А скорее всего не внимательно смотрите лог. Вот реальная причина ошибки из вопроса: `Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The port number 31.31.196.61 is not valid.`

Comment: ошибка другая, я пересмотрел (см. код выше), но всё равно ругается на соединение

Comment: [Как починить android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/506131/11515)