# Подскажите почему база данных не заполняется

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, jdbc

Подскажите почему в базе данных ничего не происходит.
Вот код класса Configs

```
public class Configs {
protected String dbHost="localhost";
protected String dbPort="3306";
protected String dbUser="root";
protected String dbPass="12345";
protected String dbName="users";
}
```

Код класса Constant

```
public class Constant {
public static final String USER_TABLE="user";
public static final String USER_ID="id_user";
public static final String USER_NAME="user_name";
}
```

Код класса Handler

```
public class Handler extends Configs {
Connection dbConnection;
public Connection getDbConnection()throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
   String connection_string="jdbc:mysql://"+dbHost+":"+dbPort+"/"+dbName;
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   dbConnection= DriverManager.getConnection(connection_string,dbUser,dbPass);
   return dbConnection;
}
public void AddUser(String user_name){
    String insert="INSERT INTO "+Constant.USER_TABLE +"("+Constant.USER_NAME+")"+"VALUES(?)";
    try { 
    PreparedStatement prSt=getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert);
    prSt.setString(1,user_name);
    prSt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView textView;
Handler handler;
EditText editText;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView=findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    editText=findViewById(R.id.editText);
     handler=new Handler();
}
public void OnLoad(Viewview) {
    handler.AddUser(String.valueOf(editText.getText()));
    textView.setText("Click");
    }
}
```

Когда нажимаю на кнопку лоад ничего не происходит ,кроме того что в textview меняется текст

[image: база данных]

В коде манифеста разрешил  использование интернета

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Про `LogCat` слышали? Там Вы обнаружите такую же ошибку: [Как починить android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506131/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception?rq=1)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как починить android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506131/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)