# Socket Client на Java в Android

Tags: java, android, сокет

Нужно написать `Socket Client` для Android.

Пробовал использовать ниже код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Socket socket;
        PrintWriter out;
        BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 9999);
        System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress());
        String str=b.readLine();
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.println(str);

    }

    }
```

,но если в обычном режиме код работает, то портирование нет - при запуске приложение вылетает.

Comment: а при вылете что-то в логах показывает?

Comment: Нет, не показывает

Comment: а где вы смотрите ошибку?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то в компиляторе

Comment: есть вкладка logcat и там должно быть много красного текста при падении приложения

Comment: Могу предположить сразу две проблемы: 1) на Андроиде работа с сетью должна быть вынесена в фоновый поток - если делать это в главном потоке будет брошено исключение [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/506132/11515). 2) `localhost` - это адрес машины, на которой выполняется этот код - то есть телефона, эмулятора и т.д. Для соединения с сервером на ПК нужно использовать его IP-адрес.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Обе проблемы присутствовали

Comment: Каким образом я могу сделать поток фоновым?