# Решение проблемы android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android

У меня есть небольшой клиент, который отсылает значения по нажатию кнопки.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void Sock ()throws IOException{
     //Отправка
    }
    public void onButtonClick(View v) throws IOException{
        Sock();

    }
}
```

Как результат, вижу ошибку:  android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.
Как мне перевести отправку данных на задний режим?

Comment: Используйте другой поток для этого, работа с сетью невозможна в потоке UI 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506131/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: Поиск по запросу "NetworkOnMainThreadException" возвращает 42 результата!