# Вылетает приложения

Tags: java, android, сокет

Идея такая я нажимаю кнопку то отправляю сообщения на сервер но почему то приложения вылетает и не отправляет что делать?

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        itemButtonClick();

    }


    private void itemButtonClick() {
        Button up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up);
        Button down = (Button) findViewById(R.id.down);
        Button left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left);
        Button right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right);


        up.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    sendBroadcast();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Вы отпустили кнопку W", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        down.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Вы нажали кнопку S", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Вы отпустили кнопку S", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        left.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Вы нажали кнопку A", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Вы отпустили кнопку A", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        right.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Вы нажали кнопку D", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Вы отпустили кнопку D", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    private static Socket clientSocket; //сокет для общения
    private static BufferedReader reader; // нам нужен ридер читающий с консоли, иначе как
    // мы узнаем что хочет сказать клиент?
    private static BufferedReader in; // поток чтения из сокета
    private static BufferedWriter out; // поток записи в сокет
    public void sendBroadcast() {
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.0.9", 4004); // этой строкой мы запрашиваем
            try {
                // адрес - локальный хост, порт - 4004, такой же как у сервера
                //  у сервера доступ на соединение
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                // читать соообщения с сервера
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                // писать туда же
                out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
                out.write("Hello"); // отправляем сообщение на сервер
                out.flush();
                String serverWord = in.readLine(); // ждём, что скажет сервер
                System.out.println(serverWord); // получив - выводим на экран
            } finally {
                System.out.println("Клиент был закрыт...");
                clientSocket.close();
                in.close();
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

> Лог

```
06/12 11:53:00: Launching 'app' on Pixel 3a XL API 23.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.sivert.controller/com.sivert.controller.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 5752 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.sivert.controller-1/lib/x86
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa2bd140, tid 5752
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa2bd6c0, tid 5767
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xae494480: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae494480: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xae492930)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae494480: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xae492930)
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:163)
        at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:592)
        at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:128)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)
        at com.sivert.controller.MainActivity.sendBroadcast(MainActivity.java:94)
        at com.sivert.controller.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9290)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2765)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9514)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5857)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6025)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sivert.controller, PID: 5752
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:163)
        at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:592)
        at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:128)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)
        at com.sivert.controller.MainActivity.sendBroadcast(MainActivity.java:94)
        at com.sivert.controller.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9290)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2765)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9514)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5857)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6025)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygote
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5752 SIG: 9
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506131/Как-починить-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: @Andrew, а как это касается моего вопроса?

Comment: у вас ошибка `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sivert.controller, PID: 5752
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Comment: @Andrew а большое спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш диагноз написан в логе: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`
Всегда читайте логи внимательно, они ваши друзья. Андроид одна из немногих платформ, где логам уделено особое внимание и они помогают даже начинающим разработчикам.

В андроиде долгие операции, такие как работа с сетью, запрещены из основного треда. Вы должны использовать новый тред, или даже обертки, такие как AsyncTask, чтобы выполнять такие запросы.

Конечно, систему можно обмануть, если использовать сокеты, но через JNI, тогда она не сможет их отследить, но это является плохой практикой.

Comment: Хорошо, пойду читать про это! Спасибо большое