# Не получается связать Android приложение на Kotlin и сервер на Python с помощью сокета (Socket). Помогите ПОЖАЛУЙСТА

Tags: java, android, python, kotlin, сокет

Я написал сервер на Python и клиент на Kotlin. Когда я запускаю в Android Studio приложение и нажимаю на кнопку, которая должна связаться с сервером, приложение просто вылетает!!! При этом когда я пишу тот же самый код не для андроид, а просто как Kotlin файл в Intellij Idea, всё прекрасно работает! Помогите пожалуйста, бошка уже раскалывается.

**Код сервера на Python:**

```
import socket

HOST = socket.gethostname()
print(socket.gethostbyname(HOST))

sock = socket.socket()
print('Socket created!')
sock.bind(('', 8000))
print('Socket bound!')
sock.listen(1)
print('Socket is now listening...')
conn, addr = sock.accept()
print('Connect with' + addr[0] + ': ' + str(addr[1]))

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break

    print(data)

conn.close()
```

**Вот клиент на Kotlin:**

```
package com.example.instalog

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.io.DataOutputStream
import java.net.Socket

const val HOST = "192.168.3.5"
const val PORT = 8000

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        submit_button.setOnClickListener { send() }

    }

    private fun send() {
        val socket = Socket(HOST, PORT)
        println("Socket created!")
        textView.text = "Socket created!"
        val writer = DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())
        textView.text = "Writer created!"
        writer.writeUTF("Hello")
        textView.text = "Wrote!"
        writer.flush()
        textView.text = "Flushed!"
        writer.close()
        textView.text = "Writer closed!"
        socket.close()
        textView.text = "Socket closed!"
    }

}
```

**Файл AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.instalog">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**И вот, если надо, клиент на Kotlin (не для Android), который РАБОТАЕТ!!!:**

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream
import java.net.Socket

const val HOST = "localhost"
const val PORT = 8000

fun main() {

    val socket = Socket(HOST, PORT)
    val dout = DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())

    dout.writeUTF("Hello")
    dout.flush()
    dout.close()
    socket.close()

}
```

Comment: Креш-отчет то где? Без него говорить не о чем. Могу только догадаться что у вас будет `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как починить android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506131/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как упомянулось в комментариях вероятнее всего вы ловите ошибку `NetworkOnMainThreadException()`.

О чем говорит эта ошибка? О том что вы пытаетесь сделать сетевой запрос на UI потоке (в коде так же не видно, чтоб вы как-то выносили эту задачу на рабочий поток). Android система этого не разрешает потому как таким образом вы блокируете пользовательский интерфейс.

Что нужно сделать? Вам нужно вынести на рабочий поток ваш сетевой запрос, а результат вновь вывести на UI поток.

Для этого я вам рекомендую ознакомиться с такими штуками как [Android Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler), [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) - фреймворк или использовать [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html) . Так же рекомендую ознакомиться с библиотекой [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Ну и в [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting) очень хорошо описано как работать с сетью в Android

Comment: Да, вы правы, я ловлю именно эту ошибку, а вы не подскажете конкретно в моём случае что лучше сделать, чтобы за минимальные изменения убрать эту ошибку, буду благодарен

Comment: Минимальные изменения это вынести выполнение вашего метода с запросом в сеть в фоновый поток. Как вы это сделаете тут вариантов много. Можно даже Java-овые Thread или Executor-ы. А вообще если вы не умеете работать с потоками, то вам делать в Android-е нечего. Поэтому тут надо думать не о минимальных изменениях, а о том как научиться работать с многопоточностью. Вот простой урок по Handler-ам https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/143-urok-80-handler-nemnogo-teorii-nagljadnyj-primer-ispolzovanija.html

Comment: Ну не пугайте так человека, попробуйте ответ ниже!)

Comment: Ну я хз чем пугаю я? Ну если человек реально не знает как вынести какой-то процесс на другой поток то это проблема которую надо решать. Я не говорю, что это трудно понять, но без этого никуда. Ну разве что говнокод какой-то писать где все будет выполняться на UI потоке и приложение будет лажать как в 2000ых

Comment: Я вас полностью понимаю, думаю вам остается оставаться лояльным к новичкам

Comment: Ну вот потому я и приложил ссылки и дал примеру куда копать. Потому что сам таким был. Просто приложить готовый код который кто-то просто скопипастит это отчасти медвежья услуга.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте файл Coroutines.kt

```
val IO = object : CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO
}

@Suppress("DeferredResultUnused")
fun io(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> (Unit)) {
    val catchingBlock: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> (Unit) = {
        try {
            block.invoke(this)
        } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
            Timber.e(throwable)
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
                .post { throw throwable }
        }
    }

    IO.async(Dispatchers.IO, block = catchingBlock)
}
```

Если захотите разобраться https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html

Добавьте зависимости

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.7"
}
```

Проверьте что бы у вас был kotlin 1.3.72

Теперь в любом месте приложения, вызывайте корутину следующим образом: (пример без коллбека).

```
fun doSomerthing(request: String) {
        io {
            // ваш код который выполнится в бэкграунде 
        }
}
```

Пример с коллбеком

```
fun sendSomerthing(request: String, callback: (Boolean) -> (Unit)) {
        io {
            val result = client.sendSomerthing(request)
            callback.invoke(result)
        }
}
```

А вот так вы можете получить результат выполнения этой функции по коллбеку:

```
repository.sendSomerthing(request) { result ->
   // теперь result это ваш ответ который вернет функция
}
```

Comment: А зачем в корутинах Handler?Что насчет  withContext(Dispatchers.Main)?

Comment: Handler это след моей обработки ошибок, спасибо что заметили. Насколько мне известно c Dispatchers.Main у нас будет доступ к view, IO подходит для простых операций с API, DB, sharedPrefs, а Dispatchers.Default подойдет в случаи тяжелых для cpu операций. Инфу брал тут https://proandroiddev.com/async-operations-with-kotlin-coroutines-part-1-c51cc581ad33

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Я уже разобрался сам с помощью AsyncTask, но спасибо вам еще раз за старания.

Comment: AsyncTask хорошее решение для начала, не забывайте, что вскоре нужно будет использовать более продвинутое решение. Удачи вам!

Comment: Спасибо! И вам удачи