# Android Рисование Bitmap на Canvas

Tags: java, android

Нужно загрузить изображение по URL и отобразить отрисовать его в Canvas. Загрузка изображения в AsyncTask никак не меняет ситуацию. Делаю следующим образом:

```
class Lesson extends View {

    public Lesson(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public InputStream downloadImageFromUrl() throws Exception {
        
        URL url = new URL("https://mysite.ru/image.png");
        HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        httpsURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpsURLConnection.connect();

        return httpsURLConnection.getInputStream();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(downloadImageFromUrl());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Возникает ошибка: : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference. Почему возникает эта ошибка и как можно её решить без использования SurfaceView?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как починить android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506131/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: И вообще загружать/создавать картинку в каждом вызове `onDraw()` - очень плохая идея. Правильно создать её заранее однажды, а в `onDraw()` просто рисовать.

Comment: Имеете ввиду, что её нужно сохранить и после этого отрисовывать в onDraw?

Comment: Чем не подходит `Glide.with(context).load("https://mysite.ru/image.png").into(imageView);`?

Comment: @Антон, имею ввиду, что загружать и создавать нужно за пределами метода `onDraw()`, а лучше вообще не в этом классе. Вью не должна заниматься загрузкой контента, её задача - взаимодействие с пользователем (отображать контент и "слушать" ввод)

Comment: @woesss в плане архитектуры и следованию SOLID полностью согласен, однако вопрос был в том, как нарисовать загруженное изображение на canvas, если оно не позволяет это сделать, выкидывая исключение? Если я пытаюсь сделать это в каком-либо другом классе или методе, то drawBitmap выбрасывает исключение Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: @YuraIvanov ничего не имею против Glide, но задача стоит немного другая и реализовать нужно именно через HttpURLConnection.

Comment: Исключение выкидывает попытка работы с сетью в UI-потоке - об этом я намекнул в самом начале (в смысле это исключение вы ловите и печатаете, а битмап остаётся неинициализированным, что потом кидает NPE). Это подразумевает что вы не можете получить картинку синхронно здесь и сейчас. Вы должны загрузить её в фоновом потоке, передать вашему классу, а после уже рисовать.

Comment: Метод `onDraw` не предназначен для того, чтобы выполнять в нем ресурсоемкие операции. Ходить в сеть в методе `onDraw` очень плохо, у вас приложение зависнет и не будет реагировать. Ваш вопрос не очень понятен, какую проблему вы решаете? Почему вы в 2022 году хотите использовать AsyncTask, и не подойдет ли для вашей задачи какая-нибудь библиотека для загрузки картинок типа Glide?

Comment: Чтоб решить эту задачу (предположим, что в целях обучения) надо сначала проверить, что файл действительно существует и может быть декодирован. Начинать лучше с того, что работает (проверьте с глайдом). Ошибка может быть начиная от отсутствия разрешения на internet в манифесте до опечатки в url'е. Очевидно одно, что bitmap у вас нулевой, соответственно надо выяснить почему. фрагмент вашего кода не дает понимания, значит дебажить придется самостоятельно. а когда получите битмап и следом anr можно будет продолжить разговоры про солид и постановку "задачи".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Андроид запрещает выполнять сетевые операции в главном потоке. И собственно любые потенциально длительные операции выполнять в главном (он же UI) потоке - очень плохая практика. Это блокирует "отзывчивость" приложения, а то и всей системы. Поэтому подобные задачи следует выполнять в фоновых потоках (асинхронно). Сделать это можно множеством навороченных и не очень способов, в основе которых лежит класс потока `Thread`.
2. метод `onDraw()` является частью подготовки кадра и в нём делать что-то длительное и тем более каждый раз - тоже очень плохая идея. Нужно сократить логику этого метода до минимально необходимой для вывода кадра - в идеале, ничего кроме вызовов `canvas.drawXXX()` там быть не должно

Пример "на коленке", надеюсь поймёте принцип

```java
class Lesson extends View {

    // объявляем поле, в котором будем хранить ссылку на загруженный битмап
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public Lesson(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // сразу при создании класса начинаем загрузку
        new Thread(() -> {
            try(InputStream stream = downloadImageFromUrl()) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                if (bitmap == null) {
                     Log.e("Lesson", "что-то пошло не так");
                } else {
                    // вызываем перерисовку
                    postInvalidate();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public InputStream downloadImageFromUrl() throws Exception {
        
        URL url = new URL("https://mysite.ru/image.png");
        HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        httpsURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpsURLConnection.connect();

        return httpsURLConnection.getInputStream();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // проверяем есть ли картинка (возможно она ещё не загружена)
        if (bitmap != null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я уже разобрался и забыл отписаться. У меня похожее решение (только Thread вынес в отдельную функцию и перерисовываю с помощью invalidate).