# Android HTTP POST Response JSON

Tags: android, json, android-studio, post, response

Прошу строго не судить начинающий программист по java android. Отправляю на сервер cURL запрос. Как правильно присвоить полученные response к TextView

```
public static void gsonResponse() throws Exception
{
    URL url = new URL("https://fleet-api.taxi.yandex.net/v1/parks/driver-profiles/list");
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");

    httpConn.setRequestProperty("X-Client-ID", "******");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("X-Api-Key", "******");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(httpConn.getOutputStream());
    writer.write("{\n    \"query\": {\n        \"park\": {\n            \"id\": \"******\"\n        }\n    }\n}");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    httpConn.getOutputStream().close();

    InputStream responseStream = httpConn.getResponseCode() / 100 == 2
            ? httpConn.getInputStream()
            : httpConn.getErrorStream();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(responseStream).useDelimiter("\\A");
    String response = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    System.out.println(response);
    Log.d("TEXT", response);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    com.ixlas.linearlayout.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();

    TextView textView = binding.txtHome;
    textView.setText("Bla Bla Bla");

    try {
        HomeFragment.gsonResponse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return root;
}
```

Logcat тоже пустой ничего не отображает. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Не может быть, чтобы Logcat был совсем пустой - наверняка там много полезного, объясняющего почему нет того, что вы ожидали.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как починить android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506131/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: @woesss Не совсем похож. Я вообще хочу чтобы полученный результат выводилось на TextView. Или как правильно сделать чтобы к response был глобальный доступен

Comment: Если это не учебное задание, в котором обязательно применять `HttpURLConnection` - то советую познакомиться с библиотекой `retrofit`. Де-факто сейчас это стандарт для сетевых клиентов.

Comment: @woesss я извиняюсь. прочитал retrofit2 посмотрел примеры но подходящий не нашел. И кроме `Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://fleet-api.taxi.yandex.net/v1/parks/driver-profiles/list").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();` этого никуда не продвинулся. Просто не понимаю как передать и другие данные

Comment: `curl -X POST \
  https://fleet-api.taxi.yandex.net/v1/parks/driver-profiles/list \
  -H 'X-Client-ID: <Идентификатор клиента>' \
  -H 'X-Api-Key: <Секретный API-ключ>' \
  -d '{
    "query": {
        "park": {
            "id": "<Идентификатор партнера>"
        }
    }
}` надо вот это передать

Comment: Статей в сетях много - почитайте пару-тройку и конкретизируйте что именно вам не понятно. В кратце: вам нужно описать POJO-модели для запроса и ответа(если ответ json или подходит под любой другой конвертер). Потом описать интерфейс запроса: параметром задать исходящий тип с аннотацией `@Body`, возвращаемым значением задать тип ответа. Заголовки задать в аннотации `@Headers()`, либо параметрами, аннотированными `@Header`. Здесь есть кое-какие примеры по основным моментам https://square.github.io/retrofit/