# Проблема с подключением к mssql server в Android приложении

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server

Мой код

```
Connection conn = null;
String dbName = "rbelz";
String serverip="192.168.1.212";
String serverport="2005";
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+serverip+":"+serverport+";databaseName="+dbName+"";
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet result = null;
String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
String databaseUserName = "neka";
String databasePassword = "neka123";
try {
      Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, databaseUserName, databasePassword);
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      result = null;
      String pa,us;
      result = stmt.executeQuery("select * from IzzumeStaff ");

      while (result.next()) {
                us=result.getString("Login");
                pa = result.getString("Pass");
                System.out.println(us+"  "+pa);
            }

      conn.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Ошибка

```
7:36:49.859 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-18 17:36:49.864 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
01-18 17:36:49.864 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
01-18 17:36:49.864 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:154)
01-18 17:36:49.864 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
01-18 17:36:49.864 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
01-18 17:36:49.875 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
01-18 17:36:49.879 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
01-18 17:36:49.880 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:415)
01-18 17:36:49.880 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1018)
01-18 17:36:49.880 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
01-18 17:36:49.885 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
01-18 17:36:49.885 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
01-18 17:36:49.885 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
01-18 17:36:49.885 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
01-18 17:36:49.886 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:68)
01-18 17:36:49.886 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
01-18 17:36:49.886 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
01-18 17:36:49.886 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
01-18 17:36:49.886 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
01-18 17:36:49.887 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
01-18 17:36:49.887 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
01-18 17:36:49.887 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-18 17:36:49.887 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-18 17:36:49.887 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
01-18 17:36:49.887 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-18 17:36:49.887 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-18 17:36:49.887 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
01-18 17:36:49.887 28324-28324/rbelz.neka.nek.tj.rbelzadmingeneral W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Как исправить?

Comment: я и использоват этот url  String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+serverip+"\\WORKING-0245B47\\SQLEXPRESS:"+serverport+";databaseName="+dbName+""; таже ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно вынести код подключения в другой поток. Это можно сделать несколькими способами, чаще всего это:

1. `AsyncTask`, где Ваш код будет в методе `doInBackground`. Пример
   [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505421/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-networkonmainthreadexception).
2. Перенести код в `IntentService`. Пример [здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService)
3. Запуск отдельного потока с помощью класса `Thread`, как это делается
   обычно в Java. Пример [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9625135/3100967), но это худшее решение из трёх.

И, судя по тому, что Вы не работали с интернетом на андроиде, сразу проверьте наличие пермишна на доступ в интернет в манифесте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Не следует использовать JDBC непосредственно в Android. Вам необходимо иметь приложение на сервере, которое общается по JDBC с базой данных, а ваше Andriod-приложение должно общаться с этим серверным приложением по HTTP/HTTPS протоколу. Если вы подключаетесь к базе данных напрямую по TPC/IP, то следует понимать, что подключение мобильных устройств к сети нестабильно, связь может прерываться, обладать плохим качеством, низкой скоростью и пр. JDBC не рассчитан на подобные казусы. У вас будет множество проблем в эксплуатации вашего приложения при такой архитектуре.